Can you transform a searchkit search / table into a dashlet for dashboard?
I created a search in searchkit and created a table - can I also create a dashlet of the search for my dashboard?

Yes, You can include the search in the formbuilder and make it available as a dashlet


Just to clarify, in the screenshot the "Page Route" can be left blank if all you need is a dashboard.

So step 1: Create a form of your searchkit, step 2: name it and expose to dashboard dashlet under form settings - got it - it worked, now I just need to get rid of the action/checkboxes part - tysm
